# Spark write CSV not writing unicode character

Tags: dataframe, csv, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have string containing unicode character(ctrl-B) as the last character in one column of the dataframe.

After writing it in CSV using spark it doesn't have last unicode character(ctrl-B) in string.

```
df.show()
+------------+-------+
|a      |      b|
+------------+-------+
|     25|0^B^B0^B|
+------------+-------+
df.write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").save("/home/test_csv_data")


vim /home/test_csv_data/part*
25,0^B^B0
```

It doesn't have the last ctrl-B character.
But if I write it in ORC or parquet format using spark then the last ctrl-B is present.

Please guide me on this, why is it happening. How can I get ctrl-B in csv at the end ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'^B' is considered as a white space, and the default setting of `ignoreTrailingWhiteSpace` is `true`, which will remove it, so you can set it to `false`:

```
df.write.option("ignoreTrailingWhiteSpace","false").format("com.databricks.spark.csv").save("/home/test_csv_data")
```